# Intuition Behind Whitney Covering Lemma

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I know Whitney Covering Lemma. But I do not know how it can be applied to PDE. More specifically, I do not know what is the intuition behind Whitney Covering Lemma.

First, let me state the lemma:

> Let $\Omega$ be an open non-empty proper subset of $\mathbb{R}^n.$ Then there exists a family of closed cubes $\{Q_j\}_j$ such that
>
> $(1)$ the union of the cube is the whole space, and the cubes have
>   disjoint interiors.
>
> $(2)$ $\sqrt{n}l(Q_j) \leq\operatorname{dist}(Q_j,\Omega) \leq 4 \sqrt{n} l (Q_j).$
>
> $(3)$ If the boundaries of two cubes $Q_j$ and $Q_k$ touch then
>   $\frac{1}{4} \leq \frac{l(Q_j)}{l(Q_k)} \leq 4$.
>
> $(4)$For a given $Q_j,$ there exist at most $12^n Q_k$'s that touch it

Here, we define $l(Q)$ as the length of a cube.

My question is why the decomposition pick the constant like $4$. I want to know whether it will work if $4$ change to $3$ or other numbers. Why there are $12^n$ not let us say $2^n$?

Another question will be what the intuition of the lemma. Why we will use it in PDE?